# Using Powershell to shutdown VM created using Preview Portal, with no Cloud Service Name

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine

How can I use Powershell to shutdown a Virtual Machine created using the Azure Preview Portal when there is no Cloud Service Name?  i.e. what do I put for the ServiceName parameter...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it's a vm created using the resource manager api (and I guess it is if it doesn't have a cloud service), you need to switch to the resource manager mode in Powershell and access your vms from there:

```
Switch-AzureMode -Name AzureResourceManager
$vms = Get-AzureVM
```

Comment: Yup, that works. Then need to use Resource Group Name instead of Service Name param. Thanks!

Comment: Sadly, this has since been [deprecated](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/wiki/Deprecation-of-Switch-AzureMode-in-Azure-PowerShell), so this solution no longer works.

Comment: There is now a separate PowerShell module so there's no need to use switch-azuremode anymore. Switch-Azuremode with the 2 module "modes" is probably the most ill-concieved piece of PowerShell ever invented, so I say good riddance.