# Using Azure Powershell to shutdown VM created with no Cloud Service Name

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine

This isn't a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31877135), because that solution no longer works after MS made a change breaking backwards compatibility.

My need is to programmatically (via Azure Powershell) start/stop VM's that were created programmatically (via Azure Powershell). The documentation says I need to supply a "service name", but I cannot find any reference to how I can obtain that from a VM:

```
Stop-AzureVM -ServiceName $hostname -Name $hostname
Start-AzureVM -ServiceName $hostname -Name $hostname
```

The documentation also suggests using `Get-AzureService` and (I think) allows me to supply a Profile instead of a Service. However, using `Select-AzureRmProfile` I can only obtain a `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.PSAzureProfile`, but `Get-AzureService` requires a `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.PSAzureSMProfile`. I am stuck.

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two control planes in Azure: Azure Service Management (ASM) and Azure Resource Manager (ARM). All VMs created using ASM have cloud service names as well as a VM name. I suspect you created an ARM VM for which a resource group name takes the place of a cloud service name. ARM PowerShell cmdlets all have AzureRm in the name instead of Azure.

In ARM you use the the following:

Start-AzureRmVM -Name $vmName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

Stop-AzureRmVM -Name $vmName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name rather than the service name you could do...

```
Get-AzureVM | Where {$_.Name -eq "VMNAME"} | Stop-AzureVM
```

But that is completely dependant on whether you have the name rather than service name of the VM, your question does not state otherwise so im assuming here you do! :D

However should this not work please comment with what details you have of the VM and ill see what i can do.